# Conditional Categories in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a doctor directory and would like to add specialization and sub-specializations to each of them. The problem is a Dentist's sub-specialization is different from other specialization. So when I'm adding dentists from the admin panel I want to see a different list of sub-specialization, as compared to adding any other specialization. I'm not sure how to go about it. So far I have a separate model for specialization and sub-specialization. When I try to add a specialization it open the same specialization dropdown for everything.

## models.py

```
class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    info = models.TextField(max_length=1600, blank = True, null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)


class Sub_Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    info = models.TextField(max_length=1600, blank = True, null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    sub_specialization = models.ForeignKey(Sub_Specialization,null = True, blank = True)
def __unicode__(self):
      return u"%s %s" % (self.name, self.specialization)

   
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('m1.views.showDocProfile', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem often called "dependent select"

One of the packages solves this - https://github.com/runekaagaard/django-admin-flexselect

Answer (score 0):

remove `Sub_Specialization` it is redundant

use `django-mptt` https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html#setting-up-a-django-model-for-mptt

and `django-mptt-admin` https://github.com/mbraak/django-mptt-admin